# How to disable back button in all dialogs and layouts?

Tags: java, android, onbackpressed

In my code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

It works fine, but if I call  a dialog, for example

```
final Dialog dialogPopupGewonnen = new Dialog(Start.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
dialogPopup.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
```

I can use the back button (the back button close the dialog popup). But I want to disable the back button in all layouts and dialogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override onBackPressed in all of your activities and for Dialog you can use **setCancelable(false)** like:

```
final Dialog dialogPopupGewonnen = new Dialog(Start.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
dialogPopup.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
dialogPopup.setCancelable(false);
```